# Passing a list to a thread

Tags: python, multithreading, grpc, python-multithreading

I am trying to launch a thread on python that needs to handle updates from a server.

I am then trying to sends this data above on a service that I have via GRPC, using a bidirectional stream.

So the idea is that when an events arrive the thread will push on the array the new event. In this way, using an iterator, the GRPC service will see that something was pushed in the array and it will stream it on the bidirectional stream.

In order to achieve this goal, I need to pass as argument to the function that will be handled by the new thread an array.

Here it is the code:

```
thread = Thread(target=handler_subscriptions , args= {address, endpoint , path1 ,event_array})
```

event_array is the array I need to pass.
I get this runtime error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Can someone explain me why , and how to bypass the problem?

Comment: Try casting the list to a tuple.
What does to handle_subscriptions function do to the list?

Comment: @kklocker `args` needs to be an **ordered** collection that will contain the arguments to the `target` callable. The answer is not to try to cast the elements into hashable types that can be put into a set, but not to use a set at all, because it is not ordered.

Comment: Using a tuple: `thread = Thread(target=handler_subscriptions, args=(address, endpoint, path1, event_array))`

Comment: If a set is passed as `args`, you might get lucky, you might not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `args` parameter to `Thread` contains the positional arguments for the `target` callable.  As such, it needs to be an **ordered** collection.  You cannot use a set, because the arguments will be used in no guaranteed order.

Use a tuple instead:

```
thread = Thread(target=handler_subscriptions, args=(address, endpoint, path1, event_array))
```

although a list would also work.

The exact cause of the error message that you saw was that one of the elements of your attempted set was not of a hashable type.  This is fortuitous, in that it raised an exception that caused you to address this issue (because elements of a set must be hashable), but changing it to a hashable type would not be the solution here, although it might happen to work some of the time if by chance the elements of the set come out in insertion order.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with threads, you are trying to create a set that contains a mutable type (a list). You can solve this problem in two ways.

This solution can bring to arguments passed not in order to the function that is called in the target. Use it only if you have just an argument.
The second one is better.
You could use a tuple instead of a list (tuples are immutable and therefore hashable) :

```
thread = Thread(target=handler_subscriptions, args= {address, endpoint, path1, tuple(event_array}))
```

Or you can not use a set. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread) recommends using a tuple instead of a set anyway:

```
thread = Thread(target=handler_subscriptions, args= (address, endpoint, path1, event_array))
```

Comment: Using a set is _wrong_ and can end up with the arguments being received by the function in the wrong order, even if you manage to force the elements into the set by casting them to hashable types. Your second solution is valid, but the first one should be removed entirely.

Comment: That is what happened with me and I didn´t know why it was happening. Thanks for your comment!